# What is the "String args[]" parameter in the main method?

Tags: java, parameters, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

What does the following Java code mean?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

- What is `String[] args`?
- When would you use these `args`?

Source code and/or examples are preferred over abstract explanations.

Answer (score 391):

In Java `args` contains the supplied [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) as an array of `String` objects.

In other words, if you run your program in your terminal as :

```
C:/ java MyProgram one two
```

then `args` will contain `["one", "two"]`.

If you wanted to output the contents of `args`, you can just loop through them like this...

```
public class ArgumentExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The program will print in the terminal:

```
C:/ java MyProgram one two
one
two
    
C:/
```

Comment: Worth noting is that `args` doesn't necessarily have to be named `args` (you can name it whatever you want) - though it's best to follow convention. You also might see `String... args` from time to time, which is equivalent.

Comment: args indexing start at 0. (contrary to C giving you the name of the program)

Comment: @Daniel, Is `args` guaranteed to be separated by space regardless of OS?

Comment: @Pacerier sorry I'm a lot late and I don't have a source, but I strongly believe they are. It appears to me as if java(.exe) is handling the arguments, not the underlying shell/terminal. Take `-version` for example, it's `java -version` and `java.exe -version`, but not `java.exe /version` (attempts to load main class `.version`). Just my 2 cents if someone ever stumbles upon this.

Comment: @Pacerier Well if you were to run the program as `java "one two"` then `args[0]` would be `"one two"` and not `args[0] == "\"one"`/`args[1] == "two\""`.

Comment: @Luke That can not be true, at least not on Unix systems. There the shell passes arguments to the program already split according to the shell's rules (with quoting/escaping removed accordingly). There is no way for the program (the java interpreter in this case) to access the original unsplit command line, nor should it wish to do so because it would confuse the hell out of the user.

Comment: @Pacerier Bit late to the party, but I'm quite certain that the OS chooses to seperate the args by spaces (and/or quotes), and Java itself handles the `-` and the `/` in front of `version` from @Luke's answer. If not the OS, then possibly command prompt (on Windows) or whatever is used to execute the program, reads the input you give it and passes in the args accordingly.

Comment: If some future user wonders how the arguments are received by the `main` method – first, the arguments are passed to the JVM by the shell's rules. Most shells split by spaces. Then the JVM initializes a `String[]` for you, filled with the arguments. This array is then passed to the `main` method as argument.

Answer (score 131):

Those are for command-line arguments in Java.

In other words, if you run

> java MyProgram one two

Then `args` contains:

[ "one", "two" ]

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String one = args[0]; //=="one"
    String two = args[1]; //=="two"
}
```

The reason for this is to configure your application to run a particular way or provide it with some piece of information it needs.

---

If you are new to Java, I highly recommend reading through the official Oracle's [Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 48):

`args` contains the command-line arguments passed to the Java program upon invocation. For example, if I invoke the program like so:

```
$ java MyProg -f file.txt
```

Then `args` will be an array containing the strings `"-f"` and `"file.txt"`.

Comment: I had to compile my code first with `javac MyProg.java` and than to run `java MyProg -f file.txt`. Is there a reason for this, because nowhere in the answers is it mentioned?

Comment: @stanimirsp: You do have to compile Java source code into a `.class` file first.

Comment: @stanimirsp You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283841/why-compile-to-an-object-file-first. Although that's not for Java, compilation in Java shares most of advantages.

Answer (score 40):

The following answer is based my understanding & some test.

**What is `String[] args` ?**

**Ans:**

`String[]`  ->  As we know this is a simple String array.

`args`  ->  is the name of an array it can be anything (e.g. a, ar, argument, param, parameter) no issues with compiler & executed & I tested as well.

**E.g:**

1. `public static void main(String[] argument)`
2. `public static void main(String[] parameter)`

**When would you use these args?**

**Ans->**

The `main` function is designed very intelligently by developers. Actual thinking is very deep. Which is basically developed under consideration of C & C++ based on Command line argument but nowadays nobody uses it more.

**1-** User can enter any type of data from the command line can be Number or String & necessary to accept it by the compiler which datatype we should have to use? see the thing 2

**2-** String is the datatype which supports all of the primitive datatypes like int, long, float, double, byte, shot, char in Java. You can easily parse it in any primitive datatype.

**E.g:** The following program is compiled & executed & I tested as well.

If input is ->  1  1

```
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] parameter)
  {    
System.out.println(parameter[0] + parameter[1]); // Output is 11

//Comment out below code in case of String
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(parameter[0]) + Integer.parseInt(parameter[1])); //Output is 2
    System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(parameter[0]) + Float.parseFloat(parameter[1])); //Output is 2.0    
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(parameter[0]) + Long.parseLong(parameter[1])); //Output is 2    
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(parameter[0]) + Double.parseDouble(parameter[1])); //Output is 2.0    

  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is the best, it should be top rated

Comment: What will happen, If I use (anyother-datatype) int ar[] in the place of String args[]? @Ajinkya

Comment: @chandru - which will compile the code but not able to run

Answer (score 18):

Even tho OP is only talking about the `String[] args`, i want to give a complete example of the `public static void main(String[] args)`.

`Public` : is an [Access Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which defines who can access this Method. Public means that this Method will be accessible by any Class(If other Classes are able to access this Class.).

`Static` : is a keyword which identifies the class related thing. This means the given Method or variable is not instance related but Class related. It can be accessed without creating the instance of a Class.

`Void` : is used to define the Return Type of the Method. It defines what the method can return. Void means the Method will not return any value.

`main`: is the name of the Method. This Method name is searched by JVM as a starting point for an application with a particular signature only.

`String[] args` : is the parameter to the main Method.

If you look into JDK source code (jdk-src\j2se\src\share\bin\java.c):

```
/* Get the application's main method */
mainID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mainClass, "main",
                   "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
...
{    /* Make sure the main method is public */
...
mods = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, mid);
if ((mods & 1) == 0) { /* if (!Modifier.isPublic(mods)) ... */
    message = "Main method not public.";
    messageDest = JNI_TRUE;
    goto leave;
...
```

You can see that the [starting method](https://csis.pace.edu/%7Ebergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) in java must be named `main` and must have the specific signature `public static void main(String[] args)`

The code also tells us that the `public static void main(String[] args)` is not fixed, if you change the code in (jdk-src\j2se\src\share\bin\java.c) to another signature, it will work but changing this will give you other possible problems because of the java [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

Answer (score 13):

I would break up

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

in parts.

**"public"** means that main() can be called from anywhere.

**"static"** means that main() doesn't belong to a specific object

**"void"** means that main() returns no value

**"main"** is the name of a function. main() is special because it is the start of the program.

**"String[]"** means an array of String.

**"args"** is the name of the String[] (within the body of main()). "args" is not special; you could name it anything else and the program would work the same.

- `String[] args` is a collection of Strings, separated by a space, which can be typed into the program on the terminal. More times than not, the beginner isn't going to use this variable, but it's always there just in case.

Comment: You used the square brackets with `args`, not with `String`. Was it intentional?

Comment: What will happen, If I use (anyother-datatype) int ar[] in the place of String args[]? @jaimin Patel

Comment: @chandru no it will not work, will throw error:
Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Answer (score 12):

`String [] args` is also how you declare an array of Strings in Java.

In this method signature, the array `args` will be filled with values when the method is called (as the other examples here show).  Since you're learning though, it's worth understanding that this `args` array is just like if you created one yourself in a method, as in this:

```
public void foo() {
    String [] args = new String[2];
    args[0] = "hello";
    args[1] = "every";

    System.out.println("Output: " + args[0] + args[1]);

    // etc... the usage of 'args' here and in the main method is identical
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Explanation in simple layman's language.**

The main method expects us to provide some arguments when we direct our JVM to the class name. That means, suppose your file name is Try.java, now to execute this in command prompt you write "javac Try.java" to compile followed by "java Try" to execute. Now suppose instead of writing simply "java Try" you write "java Try 1". Here you have passed an argument "1". This will be taken by your main method even if you don't use it in your code.

If you want to check whether your main method has actually taken the argument "1" or not. Simply, inside your main method type the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Argument is: "+args[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

When you finish your code, you will turn it into a file with the extension .java, which can be run by double clicking it, but  also throughout a console (terminal on a mac, cmd.exe on windows) which lets the user do many things. One thing is they can see console messages (System.out.print or System.out.println) which they can't see if they double click. Another thing they can do is specify parameters, so normally you would use the line

```
java -jar MyCode.jar
```

after navigating to the folder of the program with

```
cd C:My/Code/Location
```

on windows or

```
cd My/Code/Location
```

on Mac (notice that mac is less clunky) to run code, but to specify parameters you would use

```
java -jar MyCode.jar parameter1 parameter2
```

These parameters stored in the args array, which you can use in your program is you want to allow the user to control special parameters such as what file to use or how much memory the program can have. If you want to know how to use an array, you could probably find a topic on this site or just google it. Note that any number of parameters can be used.

Answer (score 8):

When a java class is executed from the console, the main method is what is called.  In order for this to happen, the definition of this main method must be

```
public static void main(String [])
```

The fact that this string array is called args is a standard convention, but not strictly required.  You would populate this array at the command line when you invoke your program

```
java MyClass a b c
```

These are commonly used to define options of your program, for example files to write to or read from.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's pretty well covered by the answers above that `String args[]` is simply an array of string arguments you can pass to your application when you run it. For completion, I might add that it's also valid to define the method parameter passed to the `main` method as a variable argument (varargs) of type String:

`public static void main (String... args)`

In other words, the `main` method must accept either a String array (`String args[]`) or varargs (`String... args`) as a method argument. And there is no magic with the name `args` either. You might as well write `arguments` or even `freddiefujiwara` as shown in below e.gs.:

`public static void main (String[] arguments)`

`public static void main (String[] freddiefujiwara)`

Answer (score 6):

in 
**public static void main(String args[])**
args is an array of console line argument whose data type is String.
in this array, you can store various string arguments by invoking them at the command line as shown below:
**java myProgram Shaan Royal**
then Shaan and Royal will be stored in the array as
arg[0]="Shaan";
arg[1]="Royal";
you can do this manually also inside the program, when you don't call them at the command line.

Answer (score 6):

`String[] args` means an array of sequence of characters (Strings) that are passed to the "main" function. This happens when a program is executed.

Example when you execute a Java program via the command line:

`java MyProgram This is just a test`

Therefore, the array will store: `["This", "is", "just", "a", "test"]`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all the previous comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

can be written as

```
 public static void main(String...arg)
```

or

```
 public static void main(String...strings)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `String[] args` parameter is an array of Strings passed as parameters when you are running your application through command line in the OS.

So, imagine you have compiled and packaged a `myApp.jar` Java application. You can run your app by double clicking it in the OS, of course, but you could also run it using command line way, like (in Linux, for example):

```
user@computer:~$ java -jar myApp.jar
```

When you call your application passing some parameters, like:

```
user@computer:~$ java -jar myApp.jar update notify
```

The `java -jar` command will pass your Strings `update` and `notify` to your `public static void main()` method.

You can then do something like:

```
System.out.println(args[0]); //Which will print 'update'
System.out.println(args[1]); //Which will print 'notify'
```

Answer (score 3):

The style `dataType[] arrayRefVar` is preferred. The style `dataType arrayRefVar[]` comes from the C/C++ language and was adopted in Java to accommodate C/C++ programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the syntax below as well.

```java
public static void main(String... args)
```

here ellipsis i.e. three dots after the data type `String` specifies zero or multiple arguments (variable number of arguments).

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
System.getProperties().getProperty("sun.java.command", 
    System.getProperties().getProperty("sun.rt.javaCommand"));
```