# what is the use of string args[] in main method

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “String args[]”? in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-in-java)

What is the purpose of this method in java. If we not use what happens?
If i give some array size then what happens

Answer (score 2):

It's for passing in command line arguments:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

I think you have to have it declared in the main method (but you don't have to use it). I don't think you can give it an array size.

Answer (score 2):

The args array contains all command line parameters passed in to your Java application.  For example, if you call your application like this:

```
java foo arg1 arg2 22 3 + 5
```

Then args[] will be an array of the following strings:

```
"arg1", "arg2", "22", "3", "+", "5"
```

You can give it any name you want -- it doesn't have to be called `args`, but you cannot specify a size.  This is so because you're not defining the parameter, you're merely specifying its type.  Its size is determined based on the number of command line parameters passed in.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use of string args[] in main method?

It passes any command line arguments to your Java application.  For example, if you run your app as:

```
java -cp ... com.example.app1.App1 1 2 3 4
```

then the JVM tries to execute `com.example.app1.App1.main(String[])`, with an argument equivalent to that created by the expression `new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"}`.

> What is the purpose of this method in java. If we not use what happens?

It provides an *entry point* that allows you to run the application from the command line.  If you don't supply a suitable `main` method, you'll be able to compile the application, but not run it.  If you supply a `main` method without the `String[]` argument, it won't be recognized as an entry point.

> If i give some array size then what happens?

You get a Java compilation error; e.g.

```
public static void main(String[10] args) { ...
```

is invalid Java.  An array type declaration does not have a size, because the size is not part of an array type.  The size of a Java array is a runtime attribute that is only determined when the array instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments from the command Line. Which can be used by the program as a set of parameters to operate upon or produce a result based on a set of known parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `args` parameter contains the command line arguments passed to the JVM when starting your program, analogous to the `argv` parameter to the C/C++ `main` function. You can declare it either as a `String[]` or as a varargs `String...`.

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.1.4) doesn't seem to define the semantics of args, so I presume it is up to the JVM itself to determine how to populate the array. I can imagine that platforms such as Android can have other ways of populating the array.