# What's the point of String[] args in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point, convention

Whenever you declare the main method in a class, you always have to do a `String` array called "args". What's the point? Unless I live under a rock, command line agruments in Java are barely used anymore. And when I try and run this...

```
//this program won't compile
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("This text will never be displayed :(");
    }
}
```

The output shows this in red text:

> Error: Main method not found in class *SomeClass*, please define the main method as:
>   
>      public static void main(String[] args)

I, the newbie Java programmer, would greatly appreciate it if anyone told my why it's **required** to enter that parameter into a main method.

Comment: You live under a rock (sorry).

Comment: There are plenty of Java programs that are exclusively command-line driven. And you don't even need a command-line prompt to invoke command-line programs. For example, your IDE passes arguments to the compiler via command line arguments. Batch files can also invoke command-line programs as well.

Comment: *"//this program won't compile"*  Yes it will, as copy/pasted.  It pays to test these things in, say, a *compiler* before making such claims.

Comment: First search the internet please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "String args\[\]"? in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

Because that is the signature of the main method that is called when you execute a Java class.  There needs to be some convention which method will be executed.  By convention it is the

```
public static void main(String[] args) method
```

And yes, you do live under the rock, there are plenty of situations when command line arguments are used.  Why would they not be used?

You could ask: why require it?  Why not just pick any other main method?  The answer is that it would be adding complexity with 0 benefit.  As is now, main function looks distinctive.  If you look at it, you know it is the one that will get called.  If any main would be called, you would have to always ask yourself: is the main I am looking at the one to be invoked, or is there another main in this class which takes precedence?

Comment: Well from what I know, nobody really executes java programs from a command line prompt anymore.

Comment: @Daniel, funny, I wrote a Java program just yesterday with the explicit purpose of handling command line arguments. I think you need to see more of the world. :)

Comment: maven?  ant?  Eclipse?  tomcat?

Comment: @Daniel: How do you suppose they're launched?  Even it's from another process there has to be an entry point *somewhere*.  And program arguments are not isolated to command line prompts.  You can also specify arguments in a desktop shortcut, e.g.

Comment: @DanielBezden Man, I must run a dozen different Java programs from the command line or a launcher almost every day. Even if it's "behind the scenes" to run a Groovy or JRuby script.

Comment: I do occasionally.  Simple command line tools a great.  I'm not going to write a web page (or a Swing GUI) for every little development tool I write.

Comment: @dsmith I wouldn't write them in Java, either; at the least I'd use Groovy/JRuby.

Comment: @DaveNewton, because it was a one-off tool that I needed for twenty minutes. If I were writing a _product_, you're absolutely correct: `getopt(3)`-style libraries to do command line argument handling is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Dave Newton no doubt! Groovy is a better language for many of these command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because that's the way Java is.

Command-line arguments are used all the time, but you don't always see them due to launcher scripts, or because the program's running on a server, etc.

That said, a lot of time the command line arguments are of the `-D` variety, slurped up by the JVM before reaching `main`. But it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: so, you're saying that the arguments aren't always entered by the user??? if so, that clears things up.

Comment: @DanielBezden No, they're not always entered manually--but a `main` will always be the program's entry point, and you need to be able to get arguments in, like a file name, a port number, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because

1. Command-line arguments *are* still used, even by *many* UI programs (did you know that [Microsoft Outlook supports some *very handy* command-line arguments?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx))*; and:
2. *That's Just How Java Works (TM)*. Among other things, it reduces the complexity of both the code (by disallowing multiple forms and possible accidental shadowing) and run-time (by not needing to find out "which main" to call). Allowing a secondary form without "args" just adds too little.

Happy coding...

---

*Yes, Outlook is not Java. However, if Outlook has command-line arguments, well, they must still be worth something -- it was a hyperbole ;-)

*Almost every UI program that deals opening reading files* will allow specifying which file to open via command-line arguments (Gimp, Notepad, Firefox, to name a few others). Among other things, this is to allow integration with "double clicking to open" on items in Windows Explorer and similar.

Comment: Add to that list the JNLP API's [SingleInstanceService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html), which ensures that a GUI app. is.. *"passed in new parameter sets when user attempts to launch new instances of them"*.  See the [demo. of the SIS](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis) for an example.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Very neat, didn't know that.

Comment: (tips hat) honored to be able to pass on a useful tid-bit to such a helpful contributor.  Feel free to edit the link to my site (or the JavaDocs) into your answer with, or without, attributions.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

A Java application can accept any number of arguments from the command line. **This allows the user to specify configuration information when the application is launched.** (From [Command-Line Arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)) and as everyone else said here, it is the way it is!

For gods sake,Please Don't say if I don't need this ,no-one else need this! :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually have no idea why it's required, other than to say that it is a syntactical convention.  In the same way that a function is (defined function-name()) in Lisp/Scheme, or there are do..end blocks in Ruby, the syntax of a Java Main function is with String[] args.

As for not using command line arguments, it's entirely dependent on the program.  Entirely.  I write programs in java all the time that take command line arguments; it's just a question of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just to be sure... I'm new at this. A command line argument is when you type in a command like java MyClass 10 "Bobby", and the int 10 and the String "Bobby" are both command-line args?

Comment: Given *"I actually have no idea why it's required"* I have trouble understanding why this answer was up-voted.  There are quite logical explanations offered.

Comment: @AndrewThompson While I do open with that, I DID offer essentially the same answer as MK. albeit without quite as much depth and refinement :-)

Answer (score 0):

One case I can think of is, when you want to have a command line driven interface for your software along with the GUI. An example is the Android tools, all of them have console driven interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Command-line argument support is largely standard among programming languages. Even in this age of GUIs, there are all sorts of hidden ways to run a program with command line arguments. I know Windows has shortcut configurations for advanced users where you can run a program with a given set of command line arguments, for example.

Java also enforces types, and by extension function signatures (look it up on Google if you don't know what those are). The main function is expected to take an array of Strings - if the main function you define doesn't match that argument signature (1 argument, array of Strings), then it causes an incompatibility.

Java supports function overloading (you can define the same function name several times with different arguments). To find which function to invoke, Java takes the input argument types and looks for an applicable defined function that takes the matching arguments.

When the program runs, Java specifically looks for a function named main with 1 argument (String []). Your program doesn't define a main function with that argument specification, so this lookup fails with an error message.