# How to get TTS (Text To Speech) working in java netbeans?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, jsapi, freetts

I am trying to get a TTS working in netbeans for java. I have unzipped the JSAPI files and added the following jars to the library

- cmu_us_kal.jar
- cmulex.jar
- en_us.jar
- freetts.jar
- cmulex.jar
- jsapi.jar

When I run the follow code:

```
package demofreetts2;

import javax.speech.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.speech.synthesis.*; 

public class Demofreetts2 {

String speaktext ="";
public void doSpeak(String speak, String voicename)
 {
   speaktext = speak;
   String voiceName = voicename;
   try
    {
    SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null, "general", Locale.US, null, null);
     Synthesizer synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
     synthesizer.allocate();
     synthesizer.resume();
     desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc)synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
     Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();
     Voice voice = null;
     for(int i = 0; i< voices. length; i++)
      {
       if(voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))
        {
         voice = voices[i];
         break;
        }
      }
     synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
     synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);
     synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
     synthesizer.deallocate();
    }
   catch (Exception e)
    {
    String message = "missing speech properties in " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n";
        System.out.println (""+e);
    }
 }
public static void main (String[]args)
{
 Demofreetts2 obj = new Demofreetts2();
  obj.doSpeak(args[0],"kevin16");
 }
}
```

I get the following message:

```
**run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at demofreetts2.Demofreetts2.main(Demofreetts2.java:46)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)**
```

When I change main method like so:

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
 Demofreetts2 obj = new Demofreetts2();
 obj.doSpeak("hello","kevin16");
}
```

I get this message:

```
**run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)**
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

I just what a program that will convert a string to speech.

Answer (score 0):

Error #1 : you'll have to pass some arguments to your main method to use `args[0]`. See [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-in-java) for extra information.

Error #2 : you hit a `NullPointerException` in your code, meaning you try to use a method over an instance which is equal to `null`. Either use a debugger, or expand you debug info by using `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println (""+e);`, in order to know which instance is the culprit.

Comment: When I adjusted for error2 like you said I got the following message-

--------------------------------------------------------------------

run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at demofreetts2.Demofreetts2.doSpeak(Demofreetts2.java:19)
 at demofreetts2.Demofreetts2.main(Demofreetts2.java:46)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

----------------------------------------------------------------

Is this because the voice is a null value?

Comment: What is line 19 of `Demofreetts2`? One of the variables on this line is `null`.

Comment: So you'll have to check why `Central.createSynthesizer(desc)` returns `null`, since that's the cause of the `NullPointerException` on the line after...