# how to accept values using command line argument in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “String args[]”? in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-in-java)

How do you accept values using command line argument in java?
Whenever I try to do it, it shows

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: Show us your code, and how are you executing it. How are you passing arguments currently?

Comment: You probably run your program from Eclipse or other debugger, where you should explicitly set all arguments in run configuration, including zero one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? See this block for how to access the `args` array. You'll need to provide more details for why you're getting outofbounds exception, otherwise use this as a template.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Argument #" + i + " = " + args[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from command line:

```
java MyApp firstParameter secondParameter
```

In your app;

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

     for(String parameter: argv) {

        System.out.println(parameter + "\n")

     }

}
```