# using variable throughout Java class

Tags: java, variables, global

This is probably a really simple answer but I'm not even sure what to search to find it so thought I best ask.

I don't really understand how to create a variable (specifically an array) that I can use throughout the java program? The variable needs to be accessed from multiple methods, and the size of it is set from the users input (args). Could anyone shed some light on this ? Cheers for any help.

```
Public class example{

 //this is the array that needs accessing from multiple places
 int anArray[][];

 public static void main(String args[]){

   int size = 5;
   add1(size);
   add2(size);
 }

 public static void add1(int size){

   //seeing as the size of the array is being defined by the user input, it's created here after being passed the size argument. 

 }

 public static void add2(int size){

    //add more content to the array here
 }
}
```

Comment: make it static like the rest. Protip: learn object-oriented-programming paradigms

Comment: is it a constant array ?

Comment: didn't you get `syntax error` for `int anArray[][]`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful and light on those pesky static modifiers... Might make a lot of troubles when dealing with multithreaded stuff...

You should think in object instances. The `main` method is static: it belongs to the class itself, not the instance. So at first, you have to create an instance of your class, by constructing one with the `new` keyword, along these lines:

```
Public class Example{ //note: Class Names Start UpperCased!

 //this is the array that needs accessing from multiple places
 int anArray[][];

 public static void main(String args[]){
   int size = 5;

   Example example = new Example(); // create instance
   example.add1(size); //using the instance
   example.add2(size);
 }

 public void add1(int size){ //note: no static!

   //seeing as the size of the array is being defined by the user input, it's created here after being passed the size argument. 
   anArray = new int[size][size]; //you can create it here

 }

 public void add2(int size){ //note: no static
    //add more content to the array here
    //do something here
    System.out.prin
 }
}
```

However there are a lot more subtleties of OOP programming, like I would have done the initialization in the constructor, accepting the initial size, and so on.

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I was looking for! I understand basic java I'm just struggling to get to grips with OOP.

Answer (score 2):

You first want to create a constructor for the class, that initializes the object:

```
public example() {
    anArray = new Integer[10][10]();
}
```

now that you have initialized, you can access the variable in other methods, such as the add1 method:

```
public void add1(int size) {
    anArray[1][1] = size;
}
```

You are right that this question is very basic, it might be better to do a basic course in Java first. The [tutorial that Oracle provides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) is quite good and I would recommend it if you don't want to spend any money. If you are willing to spend some money, [Liangs introduction to Java, the comprehensive editio](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/)n is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are initializing it incorrectly.

```
int anArray[][];
```

should be:

```
int[][] anArray;
```

this is how you set up a variable. First you declare your type in this case an int, however it is an int that is an 2d array so you must use int[][]. It should be able to accessed throughout this class at this point.

Now in main method, you must get the user input using args[] if that is the way you want to get it. Right now you are setting a value of 5 yourself.

int size = args[0] might work if you know how args[] works. 
Here is an explanation for that: [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-in-java)

Once you get your size integer you must call the constructor for anArray, because right now it has not been constructed. 
this would look like (if you want it to be a square):

```
anArray = new int[size][size]
```

This link may help shed more light on how to create 2d arrays: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/CreatingaTwoDimensionalArray.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
static int anArray[][];
```

Static variables can be accessed by static and non-static methods.

Non-static variables cannot be accessed by static method.

Comment: While your arguments are valid, and solve the immediate issue the OP has, I won't agree that this is the way to teach the ways of proper OOP to someone inexperienced.

Comment: @ppeterka I agree with you . Instead of adding it as comments in your answer I made it as another answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended creating a new project in whatever editor you are using (eclipse or someth I assume), then make a class file containing the main program that builds objects of your other (logical classes or GUI) fx.

A good way to setup a class would be something like this:

```
class ClassYourMaking {

    // Field Values go here. (variables that are used throughout a 
    // class is called field values).

    variable1; (notice no instanciation.)
    variable 2;
    // etc.

    // Constructor(s).
    public ClassYourMaking() {  // perhaps some params if it makes sense.
        // field values are usually initialized in the constructor somehow.
    }

    // Methods goes here.

    public void method1() {
        // something.
    }


}
```

Then you could have a main program, it's not necessarily the only way to go but you might as well get used to good practice in making a small main program.

```
class ClassYourMakingsMainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassYourMaking newInstance = new ClassYourMaking();

        // you can then reach into the object of your class like so:

        newInstance.method1();
    }
}
```

If all this makes no sense to you, do yourself a favor and read up on class hierarchies and working with objects in Java. It can be abit hard to get through the first couple of miles, but once you get used to it you won't have so many problems.