# Why do we usually start programs with public static void main('String[] args')?

Tags: java, string, public, args

I understand why public static void main is used, I also know that String[] args creates a 1-D array called args which contains strings. But why must we have this with in the parenthesis?

Comment: This question is better answered by a beginner Java book where they can cover this kind of question in more depth.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java

Answer (score 2):

The `String[] args` is to supply all the arguments that may be delivered to your program from the command line. Say for example you wanted a filepath as a parameter to your main, you can type it with the command line and it will pass that as the first element in the array. It allows you to pass nothing, or many things when running your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The Java language was specified that the `main` method must take exactly one parameter of type `String[]`.  It can be named any valid identifier you want; it's only a convention that it's named `args`.  It can even be `String...`.  Here's the specification, from the [JLS, Section 12.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of `String`. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)
> ```

It could even be

```
public static void main(String[] zzyzx)
```

but the parameter must be there.

Comment: He's asking about the parenthesis not the parameter.

Comment: @dvallejo The "this" in "But why must we have this with in the parenthesis?" refers to "a 1-D array called args which contains strings", the most recent thing referred to in the question, unless the OP would like to clarify, by editing the question to be more clear.