# Java command line

Tags: java

If MyProg.java were compiled as an application and then run from the command line as:

```
java MyProg I like tests
```

what would be the value of `args[ 1 ]` inside the `main( )` method?

1. MyProg
2. "I"
3. "like"
4. 3
5. 4
6. null until a value is assigned

Comment: @Satya No need, mate, I can read minds. Just gimme a few minutes.

Comment: It is not the code I just saw the same question but couldnt understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "String args\[\]"? parameter in main method Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

Answer (score 1):

Arguments come in as an array, which are 0-based.

```
java myProgram a b c
```

means

```
args[0] == 'a'
args[1] == 'b'
args[2] == 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a `String`, "`like`". The class file being run isn't included in the arguments array.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CommandLine 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
    }
}
```

For Running :
  java CommandLine aaa  bbb

Output -

```
 aaa
 bbb
```

Here aaa is treated as first and bbb is treated as second argument for command line.