# Getting user int input - This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]

Tags: java, class, input, java.util.scanner, program-entry-point

Any ideas why I keep getting a runtime error with this?  I am very new, please go easy on me.  I am trying to accept user input to generate a very simple encryption of a file.  I am getting an error:

Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

I have a main methor accepting string[]!  I am lost.  Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Encryption
{

public static void main(String[] args, String existing, String encrypted) throws IOException
   {

   boolean eof = false;
   int key = 10;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   key = scan.nextInt();

 /* Your encryption program should work like a filter, reading the contents of one file...
 */

   FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(existing);
   DataInputStream inFile = new DataInputStream(inStream);

   FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(encrypted);
   DataOutputStream outFile = new DataOutputStream(outStream);

   while (!eof)
   {
      try
      {
         byte input = inFile.readByte();

 /* modifying the data into a code...
  */            
          input += key;

 /* and then writing the coded contents out to a second file.
 * The second file will be a version of the first file, but written in a secret code.
 */            

      outFile.writeByte(input);
      }
      catch (EOFException e)
      {
         eof = true;
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method needs to take only String[] args. In your example you have encrypted and existing as Strings. The JVM will not recognize your main method if it has different input parameters.

So instead of

```
main(String[] args, String existing, String encrypted)
```

you should have

```
main(String[] args)
```

Then get the two arguments that you need from the args array and assign them to Strings with the same name. For example:

```
String existing = args[0];
String encrypted = args[1];
```

You could also collect these with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is accepting String[], true, but it is also accepting other arguments as well, notably String and String.

Your main method must have the signature `public static void main(String args[])`.

In Java, methods are called according their *method signature*. Lots of information can be found online about this, but essentially methods are called according to both their name and the parameters they take. This means that a method `myMethod(int)` and `myMethod(String)` and `myMethod(int, int)` are all different methods and can be called separately (this is incidentally referred to as *method overloading*).

Answer (score 0):

Your main method needs to be defined with a parameter list consisting only of `String[] args`. You have also passed `String existing, String encrypted` which means the JVM ignores or overlooks your main method.

Take a look at this post to understand how to pass those arguments using the `args` param. [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)