# What is in argv?

Tags: java, database

```
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

      Connection connection = DatabaseDriverExtender.connectOrCreateDataBase();
      if (connection == null) {
        System.out.print("NOOO");
      }
      try {
        //TODO Check what is in argv 
        //If it is -1
        /*
         * TODO This is for the first run only!
         * Add this code:
         * DatabaseDriverExtender.initialize(connection);
         * Then add code to create your first account, an administrator with a password
         * Once this is done, create an employee account as well.
         * 
         */
```

How do I check what is in argv? I'm not familiar with this.

I'm assuming it checks if the database is already created or not. If its not created its -1. How would I check what is in argv and find when its -1?

argv is a String[] ?

Comment: "I'm assuming it checks if the database is already created or not." Why?

Comment: In the main function, argv will be an array of the arguments passed to it from the command line.

Comment: @Dabiuteef I'm trying to do it like that. -1 would be first run only. I just don't know how too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "argv" is just a String array.

For your code u can just do something like that:

```
if (argv.length > 0) {
//check if argv[0].equals("-1") or something like that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] argv is a collection of Strings, separated by a space, which can be typed into the program on the terminal. You can find the more detail about it on this link:

[What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
//when using main method argv cannot be null. But if using somehwere else check if array is not null and then access the elements
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int len=argv.length;
    System.out.println("No. of elements :"+len);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        String indexValue=argv[i];
        System.out.println("Array Index value:"+indexValue);
        if("-1".equals(indexValue)){
            //value is -1
        }else{
            //value is not -1
        }
    }
}
```