# May Java main args be null

Tags: java, command-line, null, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

The Java `main` method must be passed an array of `String`s ([traditionally named `args`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)). That is, the signature of `main` must be

```
 public static main(String[] args)
```

or

```
 public static main(String... args)
```

That is the constraint on the code that an application programmer must write.
But is the runtime environment, which "calls" your `main` method allowed (according to the language or JVM specification) to provide `null` references for `args`. That is, is it valid for the runtime environment to start your program in manners equivalent to the following:

```
 MyClass.main(null);

 MyClass.main(new String[]{null})
```

Comment: No. You would not get `null`. You would get an empty `String[]`. There is no way to pass a Java `null` at the command line.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No way using Linux or Windows executing Java in the normal manner, using the common `java` program. But that is not the only permitted manner of starting a Java program allowed. This question has the [tag:language-lawyer] tag for a reason.

Comment: And how would the null then be passed to the entry point? The signature is what it is because it maps to the traditional C entry point. Although, language-lawyer, it must return `void` in Java (and it's bad form to omit the return type in C too - where it wouldn't take a `String`).

Comment: I think there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358603/java-args-array-in-main-method-confusion-null-check

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The runtime environment can construct the initail call to the `main` function in many possible ways, It might be s special driver class in Java, which would have a call like the examples I give. It might actually be C++ code that stuffs C `structs` that onto the stack.

Comment: @EugenePodoliako Good catch. I'd failed to find that question.