# Does "args" have to be included in the main method?

Tags: java, methods, arguments, program-entry-point, args

In the standard `public static void main(String[] args)`, I have noticed that (at least in Dr. Java), you can use other words besides `args`, but I have never seen any code that does deviate from this name.

My questions are

- Will using other words work in all versions of Java and development environments?
- Is the use of `args` just a convention?
- If I use other names, will it be looked down upon?

Thank you for any help! I'm having trouble finding any answers online.

Comment: The answers are yes, yes, and yes. =)

Comment: Yes, yes, not especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the args variable is just convention. The variable name can be changed, but it is convention and you would be looked down upon. [Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java/890980).

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as the 10-minute delay is up!

Comment: Neat thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

The docs at Oracle states, "You can name the argument anything you want, but most programmers choose "args" or "argv"."

Answer (score 2):

`args` is short from `arguments` and purpose of that array is to hold values provided when we start Java application like

```
java YourClass argument0 argument1 argument2
```

You can change name of any method parameter (compiler doesn't save those names anyway so they are only present at `.java` file, and are replaced by other values at `.class` file) including `args`, but I would leave it as. As someone said:

> Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live.

so don't do unnecessary changes.

You can also *remove* that argument, but this way you will create your own separate method which will be called `main`, but will no longer be [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java). This means you will not be able to run it directly via

```
java YourClass
```

command because JVM would be searching for `public static void main(String[])` method in `YourClass` but since your method will not fit this signature it wouldn't be treated as valid entry point.