# As i have seen (String[] args) is used to give inputs through Command Line in JAVA. But why we should write it even we are using an IDE like eclips?

Tags: java

As I have seen (String[] args) is used to give inputs through Command Line in JAVA. But why we should write it even we are using an IDE like eclipse?

Comment: you mean for the main method? even in an IDE you can pass parameters to the main method

Comment: Because JVM is written in C, and thats the callback the JVM gives you. And not everyone uses an IDE, so compiled programs/jars shouldn't conform to IDEs only.

Comment: It is a way to parametrize your application. Even in the IDE or for a graphical application it makes sense: file to open or such.

Comment: Cause you can add argument through eclipse (look [here](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_arg.htm))

Comment: @Shark - It is nothing to do with the implementation language for the JVM.

Comment: @StephenC yes, I am aware, but I had nothing better to say really; it's a pretty logical extension of `main (int argc, char** argv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an IDE is not a substitute for the Java language. The language itself expects to take a `String[]` for its `main` method's arguments. People that are not using an IDE will need this as well in order to make their program work.

---

PS: Take note that you can [input command lines in an IDE](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) when executing a program such as a Java `main` program. This how you are supposed to use it, in order to simulate a Java execution from an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Link to similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

So the java compiler **javac** (after ver 1.7) is designed in a way that

when ever **any class is complied in java** it first **checks** the main function with signature

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If it is found then only the program is going to run
otherwise it will show you an error

Giving you a YT video link of Durga Sir
explained in detailed manner

[Part 1](https://youtu.be/by58arnoV4c) (8 min) enough for this question

[Part 2](https://youtu.be/L0SdH2Dtrnw) (10 min) for some more details

*After watching this you will never have any doubt in main method*

Because same question I also have why we create String array