# What do green triangles in Intellij mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why can't I run particular classes in Intellij? For instance, I have following classes in the same project, but I can't run all of them. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Do they have a main method? If not, how could they be run?

Comment: Afaik, the ones with the triangles have a runnable `main`. If they don't have a triangle, they must either not have a main, or the signature for the `main` is incorrect. We can't say without seeing them.

Answer (score 2):

These classes have methods with the signature `public static void main(String[])`, [the entry point for a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37835237/3000387). Classes that don't have a method with this signature will (with some exceptions, i.e. JavaFX' [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)) not be shown as runnable by IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html) it denotes a:

> Java class that contains declaration of the main() method.

If you want to run the program you will need to add a `main()`

[image]