# How to use Java Code in JMeter which generates some HKSTD id ? This id will be use in further http request sampler

Tags: java, jmeter

I am working on a project where hkstd id generates and this id used by further HTTP Request Sampler. This hkstd id is generated by java code which developer has provided. My scenario is that I have to call first this java code which will return the id and then i will use this in my HTTP request. I have tried to call this Java code in Beanshell Sampler and in JSR223 Sampler but no result though this sampler passes the result without any error. When I try to put log/System.out then it prints nothing. I am not sure whether my code is running/calling or not ?

Thanks in advance!

[image: JMeter Sampler for this java code]

Answer (score 1):

Remove class and main method and just enter your code, e.g.:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String contextRoot = "root";
String csrfToken = "a";
String url = "http://www.google.com/root?ta=b&_hkstd=1234c=d";

String urlWithQueryString = removeParamsAndHost(url, contextRoot);
String token = getHashValueOfUrl(urlWithQueryString, csrfToken);
String urlWithToken = findurlWithToken(url, token);

private static String findurlWithToken(String url, String token) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(removeParams(url));
    if (builder.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        builder.append("?");
    } else {
        builder.append("&");
    }
    builder.append("_hkstd").append("=").append(token);
    ;
    return builder.toString();

}

private static String removeParamsAndHost(String url, String contextRoot) {
    if (url.indexOf("_hkstd") != -1) {
        return url.substring(url.indexOf(contextRoot), url.indexOf("_hkstd") - 1);
    } else {
        return url.substring(url.indexOf(contextRoot));
    }
}

private static String removeParams(String url) {
    if (url.indexOf("_hkstd") != -1) {
        return url.substring(0, url.indexOf("_hkstd") - 1);
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}

public static String getHashValueOfUrl(String url, String csrfToken) {
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(url + csrfToken);
}
```

You can add a JMeter variable you can use later using `vars.put`:

```
vars.put("url", urlWithToken );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this Java class as it is:

1. Compile the source code provided by the developer and put the resulting .jar file under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   AppendHtstd.main()
   ```
5. That's it, your class will be executed by JMeter

   [image]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about custom scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! There is one constraint here as I have pass some values to the Java code also like: Cookies/URL/contextRoot here:                                  
         String contextRoot = "root";
        String csrfToken = <token from cookies > ;
        String url = "url";                                                                                         
   Is this possible to pass the values here at runtime by following your approach?

Comment: You can amend your Java code to read the values from [`args`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java) and return the generated string

Comment: Sorry for the kind of silly question but from where I will pass the parameters to this file after modification? One more doubt do I need to call like this:                                       var hkstd= AppendHtstd.main() so that return string stored in the variable.