# Why do we use a String array in the main function of Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, program-entry-point

I am talking about the (String[] args) writen inside the brackets of main function

```
 public class Rotate_array {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
 }
```

Comment: to pass arguments to your code

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "String args\[\]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

Comment: well before edit you wrote String args[] that is also correct form, btw I dont know exactly why we use it but it represents an array(list)of String values and the "args" is just the variable name for the array of String and you can write anything in place of args .... For full answer you can check out this question   : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java