# i run the rmi program below but it shows command execution failed

Tags: java, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

This program should send a text message from client to the server. i finished compiled the file. the server.java runs successfully but the client.java shows error.
the error list is too long so i only screenshot few lines.
[image]

this is the code
**ReceiverMessageInterface.java**

```
package com.mycompany.dsa3;
import java.rmi.*;

public interface ReceiveMessageInterface extends Remote{
  void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**RmiServer.java**

```
package com.mycompany.dsa3;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RmiServer extends 
  java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements ReceiveMessageInterface{
  String address;
  Registry registry; 

  public void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException{
  System.out.println(x);
  }
  
  public RmiServer() throws RemoteException{
  try{  
  address = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("can't get inet address.");
  }
  int port=3232; 
  System.out.println("this address=" + address +  ",port=" + port);
  try{
  registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
  registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
  }
  catch(RemoteException e){
  System.out.println("remote exception"+ e);
  }
  }
  static public void main(String args[]){
  try{
  RmiServer server = new RmiServer();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
  }
  }
}
```

**RmiClient.java**

```
package com.mycompany.dsa3;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RmiClient{
  static public void main(String args[]){
  ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
  Registry registry;
  String serverAddress=args[0];
  String serverPort=args[1];
  String text=args[2];
  System.out.println    ("sending " + text + " to " +serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
  try{
  registry=LocateRegistry.getRegistry
  (serverAddress,(new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
  rmiServer=(ReceiveMessageInterface)(registry.lookup("rmiServer"));
  // call the remote method
  rmiServer.receiveMessage(text);
  }
  catch(RemoteException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(NotBoundException e){
  System.err.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

please help me to correct the code. thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:rmi].

Answer (score 0):

It seems error occurred while reading element from args array.
Please check length of argument you are passing.
We should also always check length of args[] before reading element from it.
Refer below link and answers
[What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)